# OpenVPN to access my LAN remotely

Tags: openvpn

I want to have the following things in my OpenVPN installation:

- redirect internet access through the VPN
- access the PCs on my local LAN

I figured out how the first works, but how do I assign a OpenVPN client an IP from within the network? Is it possible to redirect the traffic to my router, so tat my router serves the IPs?

Thank you!

Yvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two networks - one is you remote network and the other one is your OVPN network.
If you like to access the whole remote network via OVPN connection you need to do a couple of things.

1. You need to add "push route ..." command to the OVPN server config so it would push route command into OVPN clients computer so that computer would know how it can access your remote network via OVPN network.
2. If OVPN server is not a default gateway of your remote network then you need to add a static route so default gateway would know how to access you OVPN subnet.